# Slicing a 3-D array using a 2-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume we have two matrices:

```
x = np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 3, 3))
idx = np.random.randint(3, size=(2, 3))
```

The question is to access the element of `x` using `idx`, in the way as:

```
dim1 = x[0, range(0,3), idx[0]]  # slicing x[0] using idx[0]
dim2 = x[1, range(0,3), idx[1]]
res = np.vstack((dim1, dim2))
```

Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: `np.random.randn` doesn't take size argument, which version of numpy are you using?

Comment: Sorry, this is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just index it the [basic way](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), only that the size of indexer array has to match. That's what those `.reshape` s are for:

```
x[np.array([0,1]).reshape(idx.shape[0], -1), 
  np.array([0,1,2]).reshape(-1,idx.shape[1]),
  idx]
Out[29]: 
array([[ 0.10786251,  0.2527514 ,  0.11305823],
       [ 0.67264076,  0.80958292,  0.07703623]])
```

Comment: This can also be written as: `x[np.ix_([0,1],[0,1,2]) + (idx,)]`, using one of the index_tricks functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it with `reshaping` -

```
x.reshape(-1,x.shape[2])[np.arange(idx.size),idx.ravel()].reshape(idx.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [2]: x
Out[2]: 
array([[[5, 0, 9],
        [3, 0, 7],
        [7, 1, 2]],

       [[5, 3, 5],
        [8, 6, 1],
        [7, 0, 9]]])

In [3]: idx
Out[3]: 
array([[2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 0]])

In [4]: x.reshape(-1,x.shape[2])[np.arange(idx.size),idx.ravel()].reshape(idx.shape)
Out[4]: 
array([[9, 0, 2],
       [3, 1, 7]])
```